# jQuery Trigger is not working for child element, while clicking from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Markup.

```
<div class="back">
    <div class="item-container">
       <h2>
            <a href="http://google.com" title="" rel="bookmark">
                ABC                     
            </a>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Trying to run this,

```
jQuery('.back').click(function(){jQuery(this).find('h2 a').trigger('click')})
```

Getting following error,

```
<error>jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:5 x.event.dispatchjquery.js?ver=1.10.2:5 v.handlejquery.js?ver=1.10.2:5 x.event.triggerjquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1:2 e.event.triggerjquery.js?ver=1.10.2:5 (anonymous function)jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:4 x.extend.eachjquery.js?ver=1.10.2:4 x.fn.x.eachjquery.js?ver=1.10.2:5 x.fn.extend.triggerVM2113:2 (anonymous function)jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:5 x.event.dispatchjquery.js?ver=1.10.2:5 v.handle
```

Comment: To be more specific, the click event from the anchor bubbles up, so when you trigger the click on the anchor, the event bubbles to the `.back` element, which triggers a click on the anchor, that bubbles to the `.back`  element, which triggers a click on the anchor, that bubbles to the `.back`  element, which triggers a click on the anchor, that bubbles to the `.back`  element, which triggers a click on the anchor, that bubbles to the `.back`  element, which triggers a click on the anchor, that bubbles to the `.back`  element, which triggers............

Comment: I understood that @adeneo, not sure about this how can I achieve this. I want .back to be able to trigger the link inside it. I can't make entire div an element because we've block elements inside it. Whats the other way?

Comment: And as a sidenote, triggering a click on the anchor only executes bound events by javascript, not the default action, if you want to redirect to the link, just do `window.location.href = $(this).find('h2 a').attr('href');`

Comment: Also, in HTML5, block elements inside anchors are okay